# Android studio emulator crashing

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio-2.0

My android studio emulator is crashing when I install and open any new app via testing and the
emulator UI is looks different, like text are shows blurry and the speed is too slow.

I tried many type of API emulators and x86 API 30 only is running but laggy and different UI, Help me to change any graphics or file changes. Thank you

Comment: You forget to tell us more details about your host OS and your overall system. Was the emulator working correctly in the past?

Comment: yes, I faced this problem now only.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my emulators are crashing, I try going to the Device Manager and clicking on the vertical dots and:

- cold boot the emulator
- If that doesn't work, I go back to the same menu and wipe the data and then cold boot the emulator.

If it is still not working, in the Device Manager menu, I click on the pencil and then select advanced settings and make sure that my emulator has plenty of RAM. Usually, I like to give it 2GB.

If it is still not working after all that, I create a new emulator and give it plenty of RAM.

Comment: Hi, S. Miller Thank you for your reply, I will try this and let you know what is happening.